# Python shlex No closing quotations error - how to deal with?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shlex

This simple code:

```
s = "it's a nice day..."
s = shlex.split(s)
```

Would result in a `ValueError: No closing quotation` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    s = shlex.split(s)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\shlex.py", line 273, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\shlex.py", line 263, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\shlex.py", line 90, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\shlex.py", line 166, in read_token
    raise ValueError("No closing quotation")
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

I assume the `'` is at fault. How do I deal with it? I read this line from a file, so I can't just type `\` before each quote or something.

Answer (score 8):

You should use  [`shlex.quote(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to safely escape the read input prior to split. If you check the docs at the link, `quote` is compatible with split.

```
import shlex
s = "it's a nice day..."
sq = shlex.quote(s)
print(sq)          #  '\'it\'"\'"\'s a nice day...\''
shlex.split(sq)    # ["it's a nice day..."]
```

The use of the `quote` function will also protect you from 'injection attacts' which you should be aware of if you are going to accept un-trusted (not your own) input. See the docs for an example of a `rm -rf ~` bomb!

Comment: I then later want save the input in a database. I don't think I want to save ```\``` in a database. Is there a shlex function that would reverse the ```\\``` effect?

Comment: If you save the output of the `shlex.split()` you should not have the backslash escapes in the bytes you are storing. Although, if you query the data and want to perform further processing on the string, you might need to escape it again.

Answer (score 2):

Strings that are supposed to be parsed as shell input (which shlex does) can't have un-escaped `'` characters. You need to add an escape character to your input

```
x = shlex.split("it\\'s a nice day...")
print(x)
```

Gives:

```
["it's", 'a', 'nice', 'day...']
```

And you can add the extra `\\` by doing a `replace` in your input:

```
s = s.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: I then later want save the input in a database. I don't think I want to save ```\``` in a database. Is there a shlex function that would reverse the ```\\``` effect?

Comment: Yup. `s.replace("\\'", "'") `